# Swift Filled plist is empty next time I open up the application

Tags: swift, core-data, plist

When I'm opening up my application for the first time I have an empty `plist` that I fill with some values (`writeToFile`). I can read from the `plist` dynamically and get those values I just put into it. This far this good. Then I close my application and later on I open it again. At this point I want my `plist` to contain those values I dynamically wrote to it the previous time I opened the application, but to my disadvantage it's empty.

Is this a normal behaviour? Can I not use the `plist` as a "local database" where I save values dynamically, and read them some other time when the application is opened?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put this plist file? Are you on Mac or iOS (or watchOS)?

Comment: I have put the plist in the "Supporting Files"-folder in my project. I'm working on iOS.

Comment: Ok, files in "supporting files" are not supposed to be modified. If you want to store users preferences, selection, etc. you should create the plist file in the documents directory.

Comment: @idmean Will try it out right now. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @user2099024 the problem there is that you can use the application support directory but you need to save your files inside a subfolder and you should name that subfolder using your bundleID

Comment: Another option is to use the Preferences folder located inside the LibraryDirectory

Answer (score 2):

Files in "supporting files" are not supposed to be modified.

The files of the supporting files group are (like all other non-code files) copied into the app bundle. Apple says about the app bundle:

> This directory contains the app and all of its resources.
>   You cannot write to this directory. [...] Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your app from launching. You can, however, gain read-only access to any resources stored in the apps bundle.

If you want to store users preferences, selection, etc. you should create the plist file in the documents directory.

> Use this directory to store user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing; therefore, his directory should only contain files that you may wish to expose to the user.
>   The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes

You can get the path to the documents directory using:

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last as! String
```

If you want to store preferences you may also want to take a look at `NSUserDefaults`.

---

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: I'm putting the plist directly under the project root folder in xcode. When I save the plist it's saved under: /Users/Avci/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FIRST-ID/data/Containers/Data/Application/SECOND-ID/Documents/my.plist. When I close the app and then open it again and try to read the plist, the path shows a different "SECOND-ID" and the plist is empty.

The path says it's under "Containers" which i suppose is wrong. It should go directly to "Documents" if I understand you right? Should I place the plist somewhere else in xcode?

Comment: @user2099024 the place is correct. However it looks like your app has been deleted and reinstalled on the simulator. The application id (second id) does not change normally. Try rebuilding and reinstalling it on the simulator

Comment: I still get the same problem. I've also tried to deploy it on my phone without the cord to the mac. First I started the app and wrote to the plist and then read from it. Then I shut down the app and launched it again, when trying to read from the plist this time the plist is empty once again. Probably a new "application id". From what I see from another thread is that the application id changes everytime for safety reasons (iOS8), and thus I should use core data which I cannot in my case...